# pdfpages package makes pdf scans unreadable (Overleaf])

Tags: pdfpages

not sure if this is the place to ask questions about Overleaf as well, but I'm unsure if this issue is related to LaTeX or Overleaf..

Anyways, I'm trying to append handwritten notes which I scanned to my TeX document, but once I do it, there a giant purple part in the middle of every page and the page becomes unreadable in general. Is the pdf size to big (34MB)?
I can open the pdf just fine in the Adobe Acrobat Reader or Xodo.

[image: pdf after compiling]

```
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
...
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{fiename.pdf}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `pdfpages` does not change the PDF in any way, it's just copied into the PDF output of the LaTeX run. The effect you see is combination of your scanner (some produce these dotted patterns), Overleaf's PDF viewer, and the zoom level, so unrelated to LaTeX. Try downloading the PDF and open it in a different viewer.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I think you are correct, as I cannot open the pdf in Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome as an example - it's still weird that it looks fine in some pdf viewers nevertheless?

Comment: No, that's expected. Each PDF viewer uses a different heuristics to determine what pixel in your screen will have which colour. It so happens that for the dotted pattern of your scanner, Overleaf's viewer ends up showing a weird result. Other viewers will show that differently (for better or for worse), so you shouldn't mind it. What might alleviate the problem is processing the scanned image with some image compression tool that will hide the dots in the process...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a viewer-specific problem.

Comment: Should I delete the post?

Comment: No, closed posts are also useful for future users. This one just doesn't have a LaTeX answer, thus I voted for closing.